Looking for title of 'body snatchers/parallel world' type of film
Sorry, i dont remember much about the film but i hope i have enough details for somebody to recognise it.
It is an american film and i think it might have been early 90's or possibly late 80's.
The lead actress was played by a fairly well known actress if i remember rightly with brown hair.
The film is about a young women that visits her old dad in a little town. (I think he was ill but i might be wrong).
People in the town are gradually being replaced by doubles from a parallel universe that is dying. The towns people are taken out onto a lake where there is a wormhole, then they are pushed into the wormhole and swap places with their double from the parallel world.
I dont remember much else in the middle of the film, but at the end, the women goes to a police station in a nearby town to report it, but it turns out that some of the police there  have been replaced with doubles too.

Sounds like the exact plot of The Lake with Yasmine Bleeth, but it's from 1998.

Jackie Ivers is a Los Angeles nurse who returns home to the small town of San Vicente to find that her friends and family have taken on bizarrely different personalities. Jackie notices that everyone who goes into the town's lake come out different. As the movie progresses, Jackie first-handedly witnesses what is happening to everyone around her as she is kidnapped by aliens from a parallel world which is the duplicate to Earth but is now polluted and the ozone layer gone. In order to survive, the aliens intend to take over Earth the entrance to the duplicate Earth called the vortex, which are located in major bodies of water, ponds, and lakes. 

Here's the trailer:




Thats the one... i knew i recognised her but thought it was someone from melrose place :/  ty :)
